# Compiler-Implemented Immutability in .Net

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, immutability, readonly

Given this class...

```
public class Test
{
  private long _id;

  public Test(long id)
  {
    _id = id;
  }
}
```

Will the .Net compiler actually compile it as...

```
public class Test
{
  private readonly long _id;

  public Test(long id)
  {
    _id = id;
  }
}
```

In other words, does it understand that _id is only ever set from the constructor and is, therefore, readonly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the compiler does not do that. The IL code for the field will be like this:

```
.field private int64 _id
```

...while a readonly version would get this IL code:

```
.field private initonly int64 _id
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot possibly know that a field is set only in the constructor. Imagine for example using reflection in some method where the name of the field is read from a database. You need to explicitly specify the `readonly` keyword if you want the field to be immutable.

Comment: This is slightly misleading and doesn't really answer the question. Consider the "opposite" situation where you have a `private readonly` field: The compiler *does* know if you try to set that field from anywhere except the declaration/constructor, but there's also nothing to stop you setting it from elsewhere using reflection. If the compiler can validate usage of `private readonly` fields then there's no (theoretical) reason why it couldn't verify usage of non-`readonly` fields too.